# Weighed sampling with computer random generate code

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

It might come across as a very basic (dumb) question, but I'm really curious about it even if my knowledge in this subjects is close to zero.

As part of a website A/B testing framework I'm trying to work for a particular experiment I would like to give 10% of the visitors of my page a given feature.

My question lies in the way I will be giving that 10%, I will use a random number generator (C#) that for my purposes can be considered to give a uniform distribution. Further on, each customer will be making several calls (random numbers) to that method during a session in my website but it will be only using (or not using) the feature depending on the first response they get for that particular session.

Therefore I am not sure how that will be affect the sample size, distribution... My understanding is that given I make n calls to the code I will get normal distribution with some accuracy (sorry for my sloppy usage of terms) after n reaches a given size (which at the moment it's beyond my knowledge). But as most of that n calls will be ignored in order of the usage of the feature I would say my sample has to be bigger (and who knows how much).

Is it reasonable to think that the distribution will tend eventually to normal independently of that ignored calls? for giving back an accurate response to questions like which was performed better (i.e. which one has converted in more clicks in this case) should I consider that extra layer of "randomness" I am creating?

My initial thoughts were that I wouldn't be able to get anything but a good hint, but after trying to read a little bit I have come to a middle point theorem what reads that a sample of 30 might be considered large in many scenarios. I would be receiving in the area of thousand calls so wonder if in any case I can consider my experiment will be getting an even distribution for the weigh I apply to the presence or absence of the feature.

Feel free to dismiss this question if needed, or just throw in some ideas in order to allow me to dig deeper into the topic